# Migration issue - broken path links SharePoint 2010 --> SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, path

After Mount databases every path links /sites broken, what can I do to fix it?

In the farm there is only standard link path /sites, no custom path?

Comment: Same issue occurs in 2010 migration. You can try https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/sharepoint/Known+Issues+after+site+was+migrated+to+SharePoint+2010

Comment: I'm not able to open site so I can't enter to site action and do some modification?

Comment: You can directly type the URL in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Even we faced the same issue when migrating from 2007 to 2010. It was rectified when the port of 2010 environment was set to be same port number of 2007. I am not sure why and how it solved the issue but can any one of SharePoint experts out there can shed some light onto it?

Thanks

Comment: But root Explicit inclusion path works correctly, issue occures only with sites Wildcard inclusion path but even that this is standart path? How to solve it?

Comment: I have just added an address to AAM and it helped, it wokrs so far.

Comment: Can you please explain the detailed steps?